# Firebase function timeout regardless of code

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Edit: 2021 feb this problem was fixed.

I have been dealing with a timeout error using node js firebase function emulator. My function was working, but now the code will wait for a timeout regardless of the code. I tried copying the example on the quick start page, and the same error is occurring.

I can put console statements in the code, and I will see nothing output. I have another function that works properly when a document is created. The response errors out, but the function will continue executing for the duration of the timeout.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // Grab the text parameter.
    const original = req.query.text;
    // Push the new message into Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    // Send back a message that we've successfully written the message
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
  });
```

> Error: Function timed out.
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:640:19)
> at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
> at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
> i  functions: Beginning execution of "createTokenForEvents"
> ⚠  functions: Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:640
> throw new Error("Function timed out.");
> ^

Edit: I have come to the conclusion that this function does work, but it just always error out. I was writing another function when I discover this error and even when I switch to this simple case, the error was present. However, in this case, the function does create a document, but whatever is keeping it on for the entire duration may also be hiding log statements too. My question has change; why is the function executing for the entire duration even after the code completes.

Comment: This code should not timeout as it's very simple, is the function only deployed in one region? Is it the closest possible to you? You could try deploying it to a second region as a test to check if this keeps timing out.

Comment: I'm getting the exact error. Not related to deployment - this is on the Firebase Emulator. Other functions work well.

Comment: @RafaelLemos I am using the firebase emulator. so I do not think it is an issue of latency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

As stated in the documentation, one of the principles of writing a good functions is

> Terminate HTTP functions with res.redirect(), res.send(), or
> res.end().

Since my other functions where synchronous, writing a return statement was good enough. However, I solve the error by explicitly adding terminating response statement res.end(). I also experiment with returning a promise, but it did not solve the problem either.

Edit: This problem continues to occur in different scenarios. I literally cannot get the code to run when using a query https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/847. As of Jan 2021, the firebase-functions repo seems to be unmaintained as far as fixing community issues. A user got a response from the firebase team saying they have been trying to fix the logging issues, but they would not commit to a date on the problem would be resolved. I would just not even bother using the firebase functions emulator. Deploying the function works fine.

Comment: I am simply running the node script which writes a minimum of 1000 records to the firestore. It is perfectly running on the local system! But it is throwing a timeout error while testing on the prod. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm experiencing the same issue in Dec 2022

Answer (score 0):

Due to the query parameter, add the slash symbol:

- `http://localhost:5001/.../us-central1/helloWorld/?foo=bar&test=string`
- `http://localhost:5001/.../us-central1/helloWorld?foo=bar&test=string` (no slash before `?`)

Refer from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1314

Comment: This actually... worked...

I had functions timing out in the emulator regardless of what they actually did. This solved it for me.